# Nginx regex redirect query

Tags: regex, nginx

Apologies if this has been answered already and I've missed it, if that is the case I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direct!

Effectively I'm trying to rewrite the a particular word in any instance of it occurring within the URL. Now the site has multiple product variation combinations so redirecting individually is not something feasible.

What I am trying to achieve is to rewrite any requested URI with the STYLE1 section to STYLE2:

Before
http://www.domain.com/name-size-STYLE1?sel=sku-xxx-xxxxxx

After
http://www.domain.com/name-size-STYLE2?sel=sku-xxx-xxxxxx

I've used regex nginx rewrites a while ago so pretty rusty. Just want to always redirect that segment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you as long as your pattern `STYLE1` is suitably unique and only covers the pathname part of the URI:

```
rewrite ^(.*)STYLE1(.*)$ $1STYLE2$2 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Ah brilliant. Cheers Richard, that's exactly what I was trying to get.